# show header even when there is no data to show in admin on rest datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, admin-on-rest

I am using admin-on-rest to display a list of data. In the Datagrid when there is no data coming from the response the Datagrid shows **No results found** . But I want to show the headers. is there anything like **showHeader** that I can pass to Datagrid as a prop . Since it is built on top of material-ui ,so i checked material-ui too.but no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to implement your own datagrid for that. Maybe just decorating the original one and use it when there is data, then duplicating its code to generate only the headers when there is no data.

The default Datagrid code can be found here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/list/Datagrid.js

**Edit**:

For `admin-on-rest`, the code is here: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/list/Datagrid.js

**Edit**:
About the message being displayed when there is no data, you'll have to make your own `List` component as well. Its code is here: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/list/List.js#L299

Comment: @glidas from where can I get Datagrid component code so that I can customize it.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a link to the Datagrid source

Comment: is there any chance of default code availability with material-UI version 0 as I am using version 0 and can't use this code as it has a lot of dependencies with the latest version of material-UI.

Comment: Sorry I did not see you were using admin-on-rest and not react-admin. Updating the answer. Be aware that we are not working on this project anymore though

Comment: @glidas hi thanks for the reply I was able to replicate the original code and getting the grid from custom-data grid now .but still no luck on the main issue. Can you help on this like what exactly I have to do

Comment: Edit the answer again for the main issue

Comment: But you really should upgrade to react-admin asap, it makes this kind of customization a lot easier

Comment: we have almost finished currently a running project on this platform .. we can't migrate now but for the next one we will surely use react-admin. thanks